# Expdp :ORA-39171: Job is experiencing a resumable wait.?

Tags: oracle

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>expdp USERNAME/*****@db FULL=Y VERSION=12.1 DIRECTORY=Load_Dump DUMPFILE=fNAMe.DMP LOGFILE=NAme.log parallel=4

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Jul 20 11:11:57 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

WARNING: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to the root or seed of a container database.

...... 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Resumable stmt status: SUSPENDED

Resumable stmt start: 07/20/20 11:14:02 stmt suspend: 07/20/20 11:14:03

ORA-39171: Job is experiencing a resumable wait.

Resumable error: ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment DBUSER.SYS_LOB0000109481C00100$$ by 128 in tablespace DBTBS

Resumable stmt: INSERT INTO "DBUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" (object_type_path, object_path_seqno, dump_fileid, dump_position,dump_length, dump_orig_length, dump_allocation, process_order, duplicate, object_row, object_type, object_schema, original_object_schema, object_name, object_long_name, original_object_name, partition_name, subpartition_name, object_tablespace, grantor, flags, processing_state, processing_status, base_process_order, base_object_type, base_object_schema, base_object_name, domain_process_order, xml_clob, ancestor_process_order, property, trigflag, size_estimate, creation_level, parent_process_order, value_n, object_int_oid, metadata_io, tde_rewrapped_key, option_tag, orig_base_object_schema, parallelization, unload_method) VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14, :13, :16, :17, :18, :19, :20, :21, :22, :23, :24, :25, :26, :27, :28, :29, :30, :31, :32, :33, :34, :35, :36, :37, :38, :39, :40, :41, :42, :43)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a problem with Datapump, rather a storage issue. Datapump jobs will be suspended until the issue is solved.

Your clue:

```
ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment DBUSER.SYS_LOB0000109481C00100$$ by 128 in tablespace DBTBS
```

A resumable error in datapump is a recoverable error, it means that the job is suspended until the issue that produced the suspension is fixed.

Increase the tablespace DBTBS and your job will resume.

Comment: If anyone gets this error while having Autoextend on, you may need to add a data file if on Windows.  I hit 32,768 MB and it wouldn't extend anymore.  Created new data file to the table space and the import continued.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roberto mentioned this is due to the tablespace size issue, you can extend the table space size. In my case, I had the autoextend ON but the max size got breached. You can extend the max table space size and resume the import process.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE DBTBS
    ADD DATAFILE 'DBTBS.dbf'
    SIZE 200m
    autoextend ON NEXT 1000M maxsize 4000M;
```

Assuming 4000M would be the max limit for your DB import.